# How to draw an x-axis without data bound to it by using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My charts:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},
xAxis: [{
    type: 'datetime',
},{
    type: 'datetime',
    opposite: true
}],

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
},{
    data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 10),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
    xAxis: 1
}]
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/kSkYN/4502/

But I'd like to remove the serie-2 and keep the top x-axis, what should I do?

I just want to use the top x-axis as a tag x-axis, and not intend to bind any data to this axis.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this option is not available, because xAxis needs data to be displayed. But you can request your suggestion in our uservoice page: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're axes are both the same, and you just want one on top and one on bottom, you can use the linkedTo property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.linkedTo

Link the second axis to the first, and you're all set.

http://jsfiddle.net/kSkYN/7664/

```
 xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
    },{
        linkedTo:0,
        type: 'datetime',
        opposite: true
    }],
```